# Best practice in PHP and MySQL subqueries

Tags: php, mysql

I try to figure out what's the best practice in doing the next example
I have a system of orders with 2 mysql tables. `sh_orders` is the MySQL table for order header informations, structured like this:

```
id | doc_nr | order_date | date_added
```

Then, I have the sh_orders_items, structured similar to this:

```
id | order_id | oPos | product | quantity | date_added
```

My question: what is the best way of generating the id of a new order when adding positions to the new order?
Right now, I am using a `"TEMP_". md5( uniqid() )` for the new ID's of orders, and after the user saves the order, I update the sh_orders_items with the `mysql_insert_id()`
But, using this scenario I face obsolete lines with temporary order_id's coming from unsaved orders

Could someone give me a better solution?

Comment: "I am using a "TEMP_". md5( uniqid() )" - why? Uniqid() on its own is sufficient, an md5 hash makes it less unique and burns CPU cycles. And what does this have to do with sub-queries?

Comment: Isn't the sh_orders_items the result of a subquery?

Comment: I inferred it was a table - even as a query, it doesn't mean that the solution would use a sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert into your first table at the time of the order (where you'll be saving the other)  Using MySQL's built-in [last_insert_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) you can get the value for the id inserted into your main table, then use it to save the child elements.  That way, you avoid any possibility of orphaned child or parent records.

If need be, MySQL can cascade delete linked data as well to ensure anything that might make it through or get orphaned during normal operation is truncated.

Comment: I'm not sure I completly understand you. At the moment of creation the order is not saved so i don't have any id to use and the order lines must be inserted with a temporary id...

Comment: So create one and use a state flag in the parent table.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution but i wouldn't like to have gaps between id's in sh_orders table. If I create one order, let's say id 4, and I don't save it, the next order would have the id 5 ..